# Convert Azure Function to serverless Function

Tags: azure-functions, serverless, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Function App which uses Y1 App Service Plan. I converted this Azure Function to a Durable Function. How do I make this function serverless?

Comment: Azure functions are already serverless. So your current azure function is already running as serverless. Y1 indicates here that you are using consumption plan so even if you convert the current function to durable function even then you can use the existing consumption plan.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new azure function app with the Hosting set to "Consumption plan". Next publish your durable function code to the function app, and finally delete your existing function app & service plan. You can't switch between app service plan and consumption plan for existing function apps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has changed over the years, but you can actually change from a premium plan to a consumption (serverless) plan by changing the app service plan. There is an option in the navigation options when you have your function app selected in the azure portal.

[Screen shot of navigation option in azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB3Md.png)